# Rename file pattern windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I have some files looking like following:

```
ABCD0123_R001_01234567_01234567_01234567-012345.csv
```

If a run `ren *_*_*_*_* *_.*` I get:

```
ABCD0123_R001_01234567_01234567_.csv
```

But I actually want to get:

```
ABCD0123_R001_01234567_01234567.csv
```

There is no documentation if I run `ren /?` so I would need some help.

Comment: See SuperUser question [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for unofficial documentation on wildcard rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the fields are fixed then try this on some sample files.

```
ren *.csv ????????_????_????????_????????.*
```

Comment: Probably should use `*_*_*_*_*.csv` for the source mask to guard against renaming files that don't match the template. The target mask can be simplified to `???????????????????????????????.*` and if will work just as well, though it is harder to read.